# Numpy's frompyfunc passed with array of shapes (2,4) and (2,1) executes 8(2*4) times, instead of 2 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I have a function x as shown below that takes two numpy arrays as the input and I want to get back a boolean value upon some computation.

```
import numpy as np

def x(a,b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    # Some computation...
    return boolean_value

wrappedFunc = np.frompyfunc(x,nin=2,nout=1)

arg_a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)
# arg_b is a numpy array having shape (2,1)
arg_b = np.array((np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0],
                            [1, 0, 0],
                            [1, 1, 0]]),
                  np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
                            [0., 0., 0.],
                            [1., 0., 0.],
                            [1., 1., 0.],
                            [0.5, 0.5, 0.]])), dtype=object).reshape(2, 1)
```

Executing the code above results in the following output.

```
# Output of a is:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
# output of b is:
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]]

[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]]

[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]]

[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]]

[[0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  1.  0. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0. ]]

[[0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  1.  0. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0. ]]

[[0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  1.  0. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0. ]]

[[0.  1.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  0.  0. ]
 [1.  1.  0. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0. ]]
```

As you can see the variables `a` and `b` are printed 8 times respectively, this is not the intended behaviour as I expected to see the output of the print statements for `a` and `b` twice respectively. The expected output from `print(a)` and `print(b)`  statements is shown below:

```
On first call:
a needs to be:[0,1,2,3]
b needs to be:[[0 1 0]
              [0 0 0]
              [1 0 0]
              [1 1 0]]
On second call:
a needs to be:[4,5,6,7]
b needs to be:[[0.  1.  0. ]
              [0.  0.  0. ]
              [1.  0.  0. ]
              [1.  1.  0. ]
              [0.5 0.5 0. ]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: that's what broadcasting does,  Add a (2,4) and (2,1) and get a (2,4).  `frompyfunc is iterating on all broadcasted pairs of elements.  It isn't iterating on just the first dimension.

Comment: you expect `[x(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]`.  Simple iteration on the 1st dimension. 
That's not broadcasting. .

Comment: Your best bet might be to show the computation here and try to vectorize it instead of using `frompyfunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at `frompyfunc` with a simpler `b`, and compare it to straightforward `numpy` addition.

```
In [267]: a=np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,4); a
Out[267]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [268]: b = np.array([[10],[20]]); b
Out[268]: 
array([[10],
       [20]])
```

The addition of a (2,4) with a (2,1) yields a (2,4).  By the rules of `broadcasting` the size 1 dimension is 'replicated' to match the 4 of `a`:

```
In [269]: a+b
Out[269]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [25, 26, 27, 28]])
```

Define a function that simply adds two 'scalars'.  As written it works with arrays, including `a` and `b`, but imagine having some `if` lines that only work with scalars.

```
In [270]: def x(i,j):
     ...:     print(i,j)
     ...:     return i+j
     ...:
```

Using `frompyfunc` to make a `ufunc` that can `broadcast` its arguments, passing scalar values to `x`:

```
In [271]: np.frompyfunc(x,2,1)(a,b)
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 20
6 20
7 20
8 20
Out[271]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [25, 26, 27, 28]], dtype=object)
```

What you seem to want is `zip` of the arrays on their first dimension:

```
In [272]: [x(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
[1 2 3 4] [10]
[5 6 7 8] [20]
Out[272]: [array([11, 12, 13, 14]), array([25, 26, 27, 28])]
```

Note that `x` here gets a (4,) and (1,) shaped arrays, which, again by `broadcasting`, yield a (4,) result.

Those 2 output arrays can be joined to make the same (4,2) as before:

```
In [273]: np.array(_)
Out[273]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [25, 26, 27, 28]])
```

A related function, `vectorize` takes a `signature` that allows us to specify itertion on the first axis.  Getting that right can take some practice (though I got it right on the first try!):

```
In [274]: np.vectorize(x, otypes=[int], 
    signature='(n,m),(n,1)->(n,m)')(a,b)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]] [[10]
 [20]]
Out[274]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [25, 26, 27, 28]])
```

`vectorize` has a performance disclaimer, and that applies doubly so to the `signature` version.  `frompyfunc` generally performs better (when it does what we want).

For small arrays, list comprehension usually does better, however for large arrays, `vectorize` seems to scale better, and ends up with a modest speed advantage.  But to get the best `numpy` performance it's best to work with the whole arrays (true vectorization), without any of this 'iteration'.